# How to create one common angular ng2-charts (Bar chart) component which can be call from different components with different parameter

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I am trying to create a common ng2-charts (Bar Stacked) component, where I can pass the data from other component and it will get update. 
Actually, I want to display multiple same stacked bar charts with different values in the same page while loading the page.

I have created one common component with ng-2 charts and created one service also. Now I am calling the common component from one more different component via shared service with different parameter, but it is always showing first component value.

my first component (bar-chart.component.ts),

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from "chart.js";
import * as pluginDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
import { Label } from "ng2-charts";
import { BarChartService } from "../service/bar-chart.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-bar-chart",
  templateUrl: "./bar-chart.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./bar-chart.component.css"]
})
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {
  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    // We use these empty structures as placeholders for dynamic theming.
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          stacked: true
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          stacked: true
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: "end",
        align: "end"
      }
    }
  };
  public barChartLabels: Label[] = [
    "2006",
    "2007",
    "2008",
    "2009",
    "2010",
    "2011",
    "2012"
  ];
  public barChartType: ChartType = "bar";
  public barChartLegend = true;
  public barChartPlugins = [pluginDataLabels]; 


  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [];

  constructor(private barchartservice: BarChartService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.barChartData = this.barchartservice.getBarChartData("one");
  }

  // events
  public chartClicked({
    event,
    active
  }: {
    event: MouseEvent;
    active: {}[];
  }): void {
    console.log(event, active);
  }

  public chartHovered({
    event,
    active
  }: {
    event: MouseEvent;
    active: {}[];
  }): void {
    console.log(event, active);
  }

  public randomize(): void {
    // Only Change 3 values
    const data = [
      Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
      59,
      80,
      Math.random() * 100,
      56,
      Math.random() * 100,
      40
    ];
    this.barChartData[0].data = data;
  }
}
```

in the first bar-chart.component.html,

```
 <div style="display: block">
          <canvas
            baseChart
            [datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
            [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [chartType]="barChartType"
          >
          </canvas>
        </div>
```

In the second-bar-chart.component.ts,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from "chart.js";
import * as pluginDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
import { Label } from "ng2-charts";
import { BarChartService } from "../service/bar-chart.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-second-bar-chart",
  templateUrl: "./second-bar-chart.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./second-bar-chart.component.css"]
})
export class SecondBarChartComponent implements OnInit {
  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [];
  constructor(private barchartservice: BarChartService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.barChartData = this.barchartservice.getBarChartData("two");
  }
}
```

in the, second-bar-chart.component.html,

```
<h3>This is 2nd Bar Chart</h3>
<app-bar-chart></app-bar-chart>
```

in the service (bar-chart.service.ts), I am writing like this,

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class BarChartService {
  constructor() {}

  getBarChartData(chartType) {
    if (chartType == "one") {
      return [
        { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: "Series A", stack: "1" },
        { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: "Series B", stack: "1" }
      ];
    } else {
      return [
        { data: [40, 59], label: "Male", stack: "1" },
        { data: [90, 48], label: "Female", stack: "1" }
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

I am expecting two different charts values but in both the component, it is showing only the first component chart value.

Please help me.

Comment: So first component is in the html of second component?

Comment: first component html containing the chart canvas and I want to use this first component html canvas as common html with different value. I have updated the post. Please check once.

Comment: So the only data changes in bar chart and everything remains the same?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: it would be great if you also post your complete first.component.ts

Comment: If you console.log("chartType", chartType) right at the start of the service, see what you get for both calls.

Comment: I have updated the post with all the components and service file. Please have a look on this.


@stephen, In the first component, it is showing only one value but in the second component, console.log is showing both the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the common component is not getting data from the parent component(2nd component) but it is getting its own data from the service using

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.barChartData = this.barchartservice.getBarChartData("one");
  }
```

One way would be to get `barChartData` outside of the component as `Input` property. In this way every parent component will give the necessary data to your common component and the job of your common component will be to just display it.
You can use [`Input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) to get data from outside of component.

You code will be like this:

**bar-chart.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from "chart.js";
import * as pluginDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
import { Label } from "ng2-charts";
import { BarChartService } from "../service/bar-chart.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-bar-chart",
  templateUrl: "./bar-chart.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./bar-chart.component.css"]
})
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() barChartData: ChartDataSets[]; // <- note this line
  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    // We use these empty structures as placeholders for dynamic theming.
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          stacked: true
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          stacked: true
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: "end",
        align: "end"
      }
    }
  };
  public barChartLabels: Label[] = [
    "2006",
    "2007",
    "2008",
    "2009",
    "2010",
    "2011",
    "2012"
  ];
  public barChartType: ChartType = "bar";
  public barChartLegend = true;
  public barChartPlugins = [pluginDataLabels]; 



  constructor(private barchartservice: BarChartService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  // events
  public chartClicked({
    event,
    active
  }: {
    event: MouseEvent;
    active: {}[];
  }): void {
    console.log(event, active);
  }

  public chartHovered({
    event,
    active
  }: {
    event: MouseEvent;
    active: {}[];
  }): void {
    console.log(event, active);
  }

  public randomize(): void {
    // Only Change 3 values
    const data = [
      Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
      59,
      80,
      Math.random() * 100,
      56,
      Math.random() * 100,
      40
    ];
    this.barChartData[0].data = data;
  }
}
```

Now in your parent component you can get the `parentChartData` through your `Service` and then give it to your common component like this:

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-first-bar-chart [barChartData]="parentChartData"></app-first-bar-chart>
```

In this way, you can use this component anywhere in your app and just provide it with the data(barChartData) and it will display it

**Update**

In order to make your `BarChartComponent` fully reusable. You can get the other attributes(`labels`, `chartType` etc) of your chart from the parent component.

You code will include other `Input` properties

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from "chart.js";
import * as pluginDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
import { Label } from "ng2-charts";
import { BarChartService } from "../service/bar-chart.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-bar-chart",
  templateUrl: "./bar-chart.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./bar-chart.component.css"]
})
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() barChartData: ChartDataSets[]; // <- note this line
  @Input() labels: Label[];
  @Input() chartType: ChartType;
```

And your component tag would be like this:

```
<app-first-bar-chart [chartType]="'bar'" [labels]="myLabelsArray" [barChartData]="parentChartData"></app-first-bar-chart>
```

Comment: Hi Asim, from the code, you have given, now I am getting only the 2nd component value but the first component is not getting any value i.e empty.

Please have a look on the service of my code, where I have written two different array for two different component but with your provided, it is only showing one result..

Comment: @BiplobBose you `BarChartComponent` will only show data when it is provided from the outside. using `[barChartData]="youData"`. There is no point in making it common if it will show it's own data  because your every component will have a different set of data so your `BarChartComponent` will not be reusable if it keeps on showing its own data

Comment: Your `BarChartComponent` will act as a child in other components and they will provide it necessary data to display chart.

Comment: may be you are right but my main aim is, how to create one common canvas html so that it can be re-usable with different data-set from different component.

Comment: In that case you can also get other properties of chart from the parent components (in the same why I did with `barChartData`). After that your `BarChartComponent` will be able to display all kind of chart and will be fully reusable. That's why I asked you in the comment that which part of your chart changes.

Comment: If I have all the charts in a single dashboard component, why is that setting value to `datasets` of ng2-charts `Bar Chart` is not updating the value and looks immutable for `chartData = [{data=[1,2],lable='some_lable'},{data=[3,4],lable='some_lable2'}]`.

Comment: Defining an input property with `@Input() barChartData: ChartDataSets[];` makes sense, but in **Angular 7** it seems to send the framework's change detection into a tailspin of infinite refreshes.  Has anyone got this approach to work in **Angular 7** with `ng2-charts` v2.2?