# angular ng2-charts (stacked bar charts) is not loading from json file

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I am trying to load the records from a json (ng2-charts stacked bar chart) file but the data is not loading into the charts. I am able to see the response with console.log but not able assign the json array to chart array. Please suggest me what should I do?

My component file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from "chart.js";
import * as pluginDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
import { Label } from "ng2-charts";
import { BarChartService } from "../service/bar-chart.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-second-bar-chart",
  templateUrl: "./second-bar-chart.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./second-bar-chart.component.css"]
})
export class SecondBarChartComponent implements OnInit {
  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[];
  public parentChartData: ChartDataSets[];
  public myLabelsArray: Label[];
  public barChartLabels: Label[];
  constructor(private barchartservice: BarChartService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // WITH API CALL AND OBSERVABLE
    this.barchartservice.getBarChartData().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.parentChartData = res;
    });
  }
}
```

my service file:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from "chart.js";
import * as pluginDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
import { Label } from "ng2-charts";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { BarChart } from "../model/bar-chart";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class BarChartService {
  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[];
  public parentChartData: ChartDataSets[];
  public myLabelsArray: Label[];
  public barChartLabels: Label[];

  private _url: string = "../../assets/dummy-chart/bar-chart-two.json";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}  

 getBarChartData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this._url);
  }  
}
```

my json file:

```
[
  { "data": [14, 81], "label": "Male", "stack": "1" },
  { "data": [25, 72], "label": "Female", "stack": "1" }
]
```

Data should be loaded from the json file and reflect in the chart.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Biplob welcome to stack overflow,

So in your issue , the json object does'nt have the right structure . I am using something similar in my app.

Initially to have a proper structure create an interface which defines this structure like :

```
export interface IChartDataConfiguration {
    type:string;
    options:any;
    data: any;
    labels: any[];
    legend: boolean;
}
```

Then define a property in the component' class

```
barChartData: IChartDataConfiguration;
```

Try use a json object with this structure

```
{
        "type": "bar",
        "options": {
            "responsive": true,
            "scales": { "xAxes": [{}], "yAxes": [{}] },
            "plugins": {
              "datalabels": {
                "anchor": "end",
                "align": "end"
              }
            }
          },
          "data": [
            { "data": [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], "label": "Series A" },
            { "data": [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], "label": "Series B" }
          ],



          "labels":["2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012"],
          "legend": true
    }
```

So get the json with this structure and then assign it in a member of your component class and then in the template:

```
            <canvas baseChart
                  height="60%"
                  [datasets]="yourComponentProperty"
                  [labels]="barChartData.labels"
                  [options]="barChartData.options"
                  [legend]="barChartData.legend"
                  [chartType]="barChartData.type">
                </canvas>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @k.explorer, first of all, a big thanks to you. Actually, what I want to do is, I have common component, whose html, I have written all the chart related canvas properties. From the different component, I am passing the different parameter and in this way, I am re-using the same common component's html all the time.

in this link, just like, instead of the file itself, I just want to fetch the data from json file.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56306678/how-to-create-one-common-angular-ng2-charts-bar-chart-component-which-can-be-c

Could you please help me, how to do that.

Comment: I am new to angular. If I asked anything wrong or foolish, then please forgive me.